# How to close inline response

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, addin-express

I want to close current Inline Response to do some behaviors.

I have try this function: `OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().ClearSelection()` but it cannot work under **Conversation View** and raise exception:

> The method you are invoking is invalid for a conversation view

So, what is right way to close Inline Response?

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is not exposed for the programmatic access. You can try to use [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal) to simulate a click on the "Discard" button or you can try [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object - it exposes `ActiveInlineResponseDiscard`  method:

```
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
sExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseDiscard
```

Comment: Thanks, but Redemption seem is require commercial license. We are refer to free api

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that.

But you may use the [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861853.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the MailItem class to display a new `Inspector` object for the item. The InlineResponse editor will be closed in that case.

To get an instance of the `MailItem` class you need to use the [ActiveInlineResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231535.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Explorer class which return an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane.

Answer (score -1):

Simply deleting the Response rather than discarding will work.